# How can I make this tile floor smoother?

Tags: tile, grout

I just had a shower built using 12x12 sheets of 2x2 mosaic tiles. The edges of the tile have hard edges. I didn't notice this until a couple of days after the install.  What can be done to make these grout line more flush or possibly round the edges of the tile?  I was thinking I could maybe regrout it but have read that the new grout wouldn't bond with the old.

Pictures:

[image: http://i235.photobucket.com/albums/ee228/constantmotion2/9730A6BF-82D8-4C6E-9D69-3B1672CA29EA_zpsglkmphb4.jpg]

[image: http://i235.photobucket.com/albums/ee228/constantmotion2/713B9211-401A-40B6-929A-C9EA2576507B_zpsqtau2lzu.jpg]

Comment: Is that tile even rated for floor use?

Comment: Rounding the edges, if it was going to be done, should have been done before they were installed. Not sure how best to recover now. (And @DMoore has a good point; tiles intended for floor use usually _do_ have non-sharp edges.)

Comment: @keshlam - I was asking in a rhetorical sense.  These aren't floor tiles.  These are super cheap 2" mosaic - 6.99 a sheet at big box.  These are for a backsplash.   And I wouldn't even tile a shower wall with tiles that aren't floor rated.  On the flip side they are easy to install and cut.  Ooopps.

Answer (score 1):

Rounding the edges of all the tiles is out of the question. Though, you might want to try to file down some of the worst offenders.

Ad hoc grout *is* likely to crack. At the very least, scarify the entire surface of the grout first.

Re-grouting it, it isn't going to be much different but it could be a little better. You don't have to get it all out, just make enough room for a solid bead to fit. Aim to achieve at least a 1/4" trough, and take what can you get. The deeper you go, the longer it will last.

See here, *grout removers*:

[Tools and procedures for re-grouting a shower](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/36084/what-are-the-tools-and-procedures-of-a-re-grout-task-in-shower-room)

<sub>Less than helpful comments:</sub>

Don't use 1/4" grout lines on cut stone tile.

Don't use 2" tile on a floor. Use true mosaic or normal sized tile.

No matter what you do (aside from installing different tile), I doubt it will ever be fun to stand on with bare feet. **Slap some temporary grout over the existing and see if it's worth doing a full, meticulously attended, re-grout.**

Comment: @the OP, put up against some of the other users here, I'd consider myself a novice when it comes to tile. You should wait for more input before you proceed.

Answer (score 0):

The grout was not installed properly.  The grout probably had too much water in it and/or was wiped too early removing the grout from the joints as it was sponged.  Removal and properly grouting will fix it.  Mix the grout with the proper amount of water and carefully wipe the tile so the grout is not removed from the joints.